# Oracle SQL: Return record with earliest and latest date for each ID and product name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table looking like this:

```
ID  Product DATE
1   A       1
1   B       1
1   A       2
1   B       2
1   A       3
1   B       3
2   A       1
2   B       1
2   A       2
2   B       2
2   A       3
2   B       3
.   .
.   .
```

I want for every ID and every product to see the rows only for the first and the last date. So the output would look like this:

```
ID  Product DATE
1   A       1
1   B       1
1   A       3
1   B       3

2   A       1
2   B       1
2   A       3
2   B       3
```

With this I have manage to get the first date only:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by t.ID order by t.DATE) rn
    from t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Is this the correct way? And how can I add the last date as well?

Comment: You received 4 answers and you accepted the only one that is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by id) as min_date,
             max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date in (min_date, max_date);
```

An alternative method is to use correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select min(t.date) 
                from t t2 
                where t2.id = t.id
               ) or
      t.date = (select max(t.date) 
                from t t2 
                where t2.id = t.id
               ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with the window functions, this way it worked much better and quicker than I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Use `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions. Lines #1 - 13 represent sample data (you don't type that); query you need begins at line #14.

```
SQL> with test (id, product, datum) as
  2    (select 1, 'A', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'B', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'A', 2 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'B', 2 from dual union all
  6     select 1, 'A', 3 from dual union all
  7     select 1, 'B', 3 from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 2, 'A', 1 from dual union all
 10     select 2, 'B', 1 from dual union all
 11     select 2, 'A', 2 from dual union all
 12     select 2, 'B', 2 from dual
 13    )
 14  select id, product,
 15    min(datum) datum
 16    from test
 17    group by id, product
 18  --
 19  union
 20  --
 21  select id, product,
 22    max(datum) datum
 23    from test
 24    group by id, product
 25  order by id, datum, product;

        ID PRODUCT         DATUM
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 A                   1
         1 B                   1
         1 A                   3
         1 B                   3
         2 A                   1
         2 B                   1
         2 A                   2
         2 B                   2

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for this table, but if there are more columns in the table that I want to include in the output it becomes more complicated and the window functions that were suggested in another answer seem to be simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `RANK()` (or `ROW_NUMBER()` if there no duplicate dates) window function:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Product, t."DATE"
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.Product ORDER BY t."DATE") rn_min,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.Product ORDER BY t."DATE" DESC) rn_max
  FROM tablename t
) t
WHERE 1 IN (rn_min, rn_max)
ORDER BY t.ID, t."DATE", t.Product
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08b7db4429353dc1db6fda8b9358a3d1).
Results:

```
> ID | PRODUCT | DATE
> -: | :------ | ---:
>  1 | A       |    1
>  1 | B       |    1
>  1 | A       |    3
>  1 | B       |    3
>  2 | A       |    1
>  2 | B       |    1
>  2 | A       |    3
>  2 | B       |    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use `first_value` and `last_value` analytical function as follows:

```
Select id, product, date from
(Select t.*,
       First_value(date) over (partition by id, product order by date) as fdate,
       Last_value(date) over (partition by id, product order by date) as ldate
  From your_table t)
Where date = fdate or date = ldate;
```